# Android - ScrollView activity hosted in TabActivity and windowSoftInputMode

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity which has the tabs across the **bottom** of the screen.  My first tab hosts an activity which consists of a fixed header layout at the top of the screen, and a ScrollView beneath it which contains several EditText controls.  The ScrollView scrolls it's content fine between the header bar and the bottom tabs, the problem occurs when an EditText is tapped and the soft keyboard appears.  I understand to control the behaviour of the views when the keyboard appears I need to use the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute in the manifest XML file.  However I've tried both the following settings :

`adjustResize` - Gives the correct functionality for the ScrollView and the header layout remains fixed at the top of the screen.  However the tab bar controls are pushed up on top of the keyboard.

`adjustPan` - The tab bar controls remain at the bottom of the screen beneath the keyboard (which is what I want) but the other views are pushed up by the keyboard meaning the header layout gets pushed up off the screen.

It seems I need characteristics of both settings, but they can't be used together.  I've heard of the setting `adjustNothing` but if I try this my project fails to build as it doesn't recognise this setting.  I guess I need my tab host activity to have `adjustPan` but my content activity to have `adjustResize` but it seems you can't combine the two as it's the tab host activity that takes precedence.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure if it helps since I could not test it, but check this answer, maybe you can set the property in the content programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/a/6138509/562840

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looked promising but didn't work :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any direct solution for this, I have resorted to a kind of hack.  I have set my TabHost activity to `adjustResize` and then written code to hide/unhide the tab bar controls (TabWidget) when the soft keyboard appears/disappears.  I managed to get a pretty good result in the end, using the technique here : [Adjust layout when soft keyboard is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on) to detect the keyboard appearing/disappearing.