# Is there a way to set android:windowSoftInputMode by Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

android:windowSoftInputMode is set normally set on an Activity but I set everything up as one Activity that switches to different Fragments to support tabbing and I need different soft input mode for fragments.

My actual problem is that adjustPan causes text views within webviews to get covered by the keyboard and adjustResize was resizing a view that I was using for calculations and I thought setting different soft input mode for each fragment would be a good workaround.

Comment: maybe this will usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138330/is-there-any-way-to-change-androidwindowsoftinputmode-value-from-java-class

Comment: Is my answer work for you

Answer (score 14):

try this each onCreateView of your fragment

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

i hope its works for you and reply

Comment: In which callback do you recommend this mode be set?

Comment: OnCreate of fregment