# Set adjustResize Programmatically

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically change the value of an activity's windowSoftInputMode? I want to set it to adjustResize in one view, and to not resize on another view (Both the views in the same activity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138330/is-there-any-way-to-change-androidwindowsoftinputmode-value-from-java-class

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is deprecated

Comment: @prsnlme and what should we use for now?

Comment: @walkmn Window Insets

Comment: it's deprecated use. Use     window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)