# Using "adjustPan" or "adjustResize" specific to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify **programatically** or in the **xml** a way to use a `windowSoftInputMode` specific to a `Fragment`.

Let's say I have just one `activity` that contains two `fragment`, one fragment should use `adjustPan` and the other one `adjustResize`. How should I manage this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the behavior programmatically, see [this answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138509/1395437).

So what I would do: if fragment A is resumed, use `getActivity()` to get a reference to its parent activity, and then use the command from the question to change the behavior.

Then do the same with fragment B, but use the other parameter when setting the soft input mode behavior.

- `adjustResize` would be: `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`
- `adjustPan` would be: `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`